# How to use the word "stagger" with time

Tags: verbs

> When cooking this dish, it is better to stagger the timing of putting
>   fish in a saucepan from the timing of putting meat in the pan.

Could you advise me on whether the usage of "stagger" in the sentence above I created is correct.  This sentence simply means that it is better to put fish and meat in the pan at different timings, but I am trying to describe this using the word "timing" and a verb such as "stagger", "differentiate", "displace", etc.  I am confused on which verb is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of

> stagger

is absolutely correct and idiomatic.

When things are **staggered** they are started at different times.

> **staggered** timing
>   **different** timing

**displaced** would not be quite correct in this context.